# Unusual characteristics of && operator in while loop in linked list deletion in C

Tags: c, while-loop, linked-list, and-operator

I have been playing around with linked list and got to know some unusual characteristics of While loop with  AND operatoin(I guess so).

Here what it is:

This is my delet function.I am searching for the key to be deleted.

```
void delet(Mynode** head,int value) {
    printf(" deleting... %d\n",value);
    Mynode *temp = *head,*prev;
    if(temp->val == value) { 
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    } else {
        while( temp->val != value && temp != NULL) {
            prev = temp;
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }
    if(temp == NULL) {
        printf("..and %d is not in the list\n",value );
    } else{
        prev->next = temp->next;
    }
}
```

In while loop I have been  checking the condition like this.
and worked properly only for the value in the list.

If the value to be deleted is not in the list then it would throw  a segmentation fault.

```
while( temp->val != value && temp != NULL) {
    prev = temp;
    temp=temp->next;
}
```

But interesting thing is if I swap the conditions in the while loop it works properly without any error. that is:

```
    while( temp != NULL && temp->val != value)
```

I guess swapping the conditions in while loop should't affect the output.

Could any body tell me why is that or am I going  wrong all the time.

thank you for your time.

Comment: who ever down voted this question, feel free to put some words stating what it lacks so that I can learn from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

```
temp->val != value && temp != NULL
```

Requires `temp` to be not null for `temp->val` to work. The first bit being tested. If `temp` is null it will crash.

Therefore first test if `temp` is not null, then look into the contents pointed to by `temp`.

i.e.

```
temp != NULL && temp->val != value
```

ps: && is a short circuit operator where as soon as it knows the answer it stops evaluation